# How Does Compiler know addition , subtraction operators while compiling the code?

Tags: c++

**I have made the simple program in cplus like this -**

```
main()
{
int a=5;
int b=8;
int c;
c= a+b;
cout<<c<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

I get the output as 13 which is correct.

**I want to know How g++ compiler knows about "+" operator ?
Is there any method defined in header file for this operator , like the other keywords are defined in standard libraries.**

Comment: No, that's not defined in a header. You can use operators without header files. It's part of language. That means that every c++ compiler must know how to translate such operators to machine code. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/NVz7nU)

Comment: And actually, keywords, like `if`, `int` or `void` are **not** defined in header files either.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Although some might be, e.g. `and`, `or`.

Comment: @batsheba. Yes, true. But generally, the compiler knows keywords, operators and constructs on its own.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Indeed, for me it's not obvious how you would go about tackling this question.

Comment: @Bathsheba Which header are `and` and `or` defined in? They seemed to compile and work with g++ without including any header, though that may be something compiler specific.

Comment: @George: It would depend on the compiler. g++ doesn't by the way.

Comment: C+ is a carbon ion with one electron missing. They are as rare as a cplus compiler.

Comment: @schorsch312 `main()` is still not C++. I would not recommend applying substantial edits to questions, they may completely mask OP's mistakes and so others won't be able to point these mistakes out to OP's benefit.

Answer (score 3):

There is no method for basic types such as int short char double etc. Basic operation for these types is built into compiler. So compiler when it sees these operations on basic types converts it directly to assembly. So here is an example:

If you want to see assembly output do following `gcc -S myfile.c` or for c++ `g++ -S myfile.cpp`

Comment: With my compiler, the OP's program is converted as if it's `int main(){printf("13\n");}`

Comment: I do not get you? What compiler are you using? If it is gcc what version `gcc --version`

Comment: @Gov A very very good one that implements the C++ standard perfectly.

Comment: @Bathsheba Really? Then why is it translating a program with no output into a program with output? That violates the as-if rule.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I guess the behaviour of the code is undefined. My other compiler optimised it to `int main{}`. My spare one ate my cat.

Comment: @Bathsheba turn off optimization to produce true assembly code. `gcc -S -O0 myfile.cpp`

Comment: Less facetiously I think that your including the code and assembler ruins the answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I will remove it.

Comment: Turning off optimization does not make the resulting assembly "truer".